# Service error: SitesApp: Internal Error when moving announcements from one announcementpage to another

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

What steps will reproduce the problem?

1. Loading the function below into a Google Site.
2. Running the function, moveblogs().

What is the expected output?

I expect all 2013 blog posts (announcements) to have their titles logged in Logger and then be moved to the new blog (announcementspage).

What do you see instead?

I see the error:

> Service error: SitesApp: Internal Error (line 25, file "Code") Dismiss

If possible, provide the code for a small sample script that reproduces the
issue:

```
 function moveblogs() {

  var fromblog =  SitesApp.getPageByUrl("https://sites.google.com/a/mydomain.com/intranethome/home/Around-Intranet");
  var toblog =  SitesApp.getPageByUrl("https://sites.google.com/a/mydomain.com/intranethome/home/2013-around-Intranet");

    var nextbloc = 0;

    while (true) {
      var pages2 = fromblog.getAllDescendants({"start":nextbloc,"max":100});

      if (pages2.length > 0){

        Logger.log("starting at.."+nextbloc+" there are .."+pages2.length+" pages starting with.."+pages2[0].getTitle());
        var i = nextbloc;
        for (var x in pages2) {

          var publishedyear = Utilities.formatDate(pages2[x].getDatePublished(),"GMT","yyyy")
          Logger.log("year: "+publishedyear);

          if (publishedyear==2013) {

            Logger.log("Title: "+pages2[x].getTitle());

            pages2[x].setParent(toblog);
            Utilities.sleep(1000);
          }
          i = i + 1;          
        }    
      } else {
        break;      
      }
      nextbloc = nextbloc + 100;

    }      

}
```

Please provide any additional information below.

1. Commenting out line 25 allows for 2012 blog posts to be successfully logged.
2. The code below can move a single blog post in a separate function:

   `blogpost.setParent(toblog);`

Comment: [This example](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_page#setParent) gets a Site first, then uses `getChildByName()` to get the to & from pages. This ensures both pages are in the same site. Have you tried that pattern in your code?

Answer (score 1):

I think there was actually a problem with one of the titles in one of the announcements.  This script works, although might time out.  But re-running it will just continue where it left off.

```
 function moveblogs() {

  var fromblog =  SitesApp.getPageByUrl("https://sites.google.com/a/mydomain.com/intranethome/home/Around-Intranet");
  var toblog =  SitesApp.getPageByUrl("https://sites.google.com/a/mydomain.com/intranethome/home/2013-around-Intranet");

  var nextbloc = 0;

  while (true) {

    var pages2 = fromblog.getChildren({"start":nextbloc,
                                       "max":10,
                                       includeDrafts: false,
                                       includeDeleted: false,
                                      });

    if (pages2.length > 0){

      Logger.log("starting at.."+nextbloc+" there are .."+pages2.length+" pages starting with.."+newblogtitle);
      var i = nextbloc;
      for (var x in pages2) {

        var newblogtitle = pages2[x].getTitle();
        //var pageType = pages2[x].getPageType();

        var publishedyear = Utilities.formatDate(pages2[x].getDatePublished(),"GMT","yyyy")

          if (publishedyear==2013) {

          Logger.log("Title: "+ newblogtitle);

          try{

            pages2[x].setParent(toblog);
            //    Utilities.sleep(1000);
          }catch(err){
            Logger.log(err);
          }
        }
        i = i + 1;          
      }    
    } else {
      break;      
    }
    nextbloc = nextbloc + 10;

  }      

}

}
```